# Configurable Schema Names in Linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, database-schema

Let's say I generate a Linq to SQL context against a database for some simple data access for an application.  The tables in that database belong to a particular schema (in this case "CRPDTA" for some tables, "CRPCTL" for others).  However, when the application goes to production, the same tables will belong to a different schema in the production database (in this case "PRODTA" and "PRODCTL").

Is there a way to make the schema name configurable for Linq 2 SQL, something definable in the application's config file?

In the data context class I see the table name attributes:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="CRPDTA.TableName")]
```

Technically I *could* manipulate that string directly, but editing an auto-generated file would mean needing to re-edit it any time it's re-generated.  So I'd prefer something more sustainable.  But so far haven't been able to find anything like that.

Is this something that just can't be done with this tool?  Maybe somebody has a creative solution that's worked in a similar situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot more poking around on Google, I eventually found an interesting approach [here](http://jimmyyanblog.blogspot.com/2008/12/change-linq-to-sql-mapping-at-run-time.html).  The idea is to create a custom mapping source for the LINQ entities, which is nothing more than a pass-through for the normal functionality until you get to the point of the table name.

The exact code on that article wasn't actually working though (aside from an easily fixed compile error or two), since for some reason the `TableName` property wasn't actually being called.  So I had to explicitly set it in the `MetaTable` object.  And since it's a private field, this required reflection.

What I ended up with was as follows.

**Custom Mapping Source**

```
public class CustomMappingSource : MappingSource
{
    private AttributeMappingSource mapping = new AttributeMappingSource();

    protected override MetaModel CreateModel(Type dataContextType)
    {
        return new CustomMetaModel(mapping.GetModel(dataContextType));
    }
}
```

This is just a pass-through, there's nothing interesting happening here.  But it does require the next level:

**Custom Meta Model**

```
public class CustomMetaModel : MetaModel
{
    private static CustomAttributeMapping mapping = new CustomAttributeMapping();
    private MetaModel model;

    public CustomMetaModel(MetaModel model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public override Type ContextType
    {
        get { return model.ContextType; }
    }

    public override MappingSource MappingSource
    {
        get { return mapping; }
    }

    public override string DatabaseName
    {
        get { return model.DatabaseName; }
    }

    public override Type ProviderType
    {
        get { return model.ProviderType; }
    }

    public override MetaTable GetTable(Type rowType)
    {
        return new CustomMetaTable(model.GetTable(rowType), model);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<MetaTable> GetTables()
    {
        foreach (var table in model.GetTables())
            yield return new CustomMetaTable(table, model);
    }

    public override MetaFunction GetFunction(System.Reflection.MethodInfo method)
    {
        return model.GetFunction(method);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<MetaFunction> GetFunctions()
    {
        return model.GetFunctions();
    }

    public override MetaType GetMetaType(Type type)
    {
        return model.GetMetaType(type);
    }
}
```

Again, all pass-throughs.  Nothing interesting until we get to the next level:

**Custom Meta Table**

```
public class CustomMetaTable : MetaTable
{
    private MetaTable table;
    private MetaModel model;

    public CustomMetaTable(MetaTable table, MetaModel model)
    {
        this.table = table;
        this.model = model;

        var tableNameField = this.table.GetType().FindMembers(MemberTypes.Field, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, (member, criteria) => member.Name == "tableName", null).OfType<FieldInfo>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (tableNameField != null)
            tableNameField.SetValue(this.table, TableName);
    }

    public override System.Reflection.MethodInfo DeleteMethod
    {
        get { return table.DeleteMethod; }
    }

    public override System.Reflection.MethodInfo InsertMethod
    {
        get { return table.InsertMethod; }
    }

    public override System.Reflection.MethodInfo UpdateMethod
    {
        get { return table.UpdateMethod; }
    }

    public override MetaModel Model
    {
        get { return model; }
    }

    public override string TableName
    {
        get
        {
            return table.TableName
                        .Replace("CRPDTA", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BusinessDataSchema"])
                        .Replace("CRPCTL", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ControlDataSchema"]);
        }
    }

    public override MetaType RowType
    {
        get { return table.RowType; }
    }
}
```

That's where the (semi-) interesting stuff happens.  The `TableName` property is still the custom one I wrote based on the original article I found (linked earlier).  All I needed to add was the reflection in the constructor to explicitly set the table name on the tables.

With this, I just needed to set my data context usage to use this custom mapping:

```
using (var db = new BusinessDBContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BusinessDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString, new CustomAttributeMapping()))
```